# SQL Server column of type Varchar(4000) should show in different line where there is *** see below example

Tags: sql-server

I have column in a SQL Server table with `Varchar(4000)`, in big string need to have in lines where it has ***

String example:

```
 *** CERPS Generated Case [06/25/2013 01:41:13 AM] C0   *** CREATED:  06/25/2013 AT 09:40 BY 0000000  AT RUHA *** CONTACT:  PHONE NUMBER 000-000-0000 X-0000 *** SPECIAL HANDLING CODE: 02 DELIVER WEEKDAY STATUS CODE: 33-VENDOR TRANSPORTATION DELAY MISSING SHIPT/ NOT LOCATED MISSING SHIPTS/ NOT LOCATED
```

This needs to show as

```
*** CERPS Generated Case [06/25/2013 01:41:13 AM] C0
*** CREATED:  06/25/2013 AT 09:40 BY 0000000  AT RUHA
 *** CONTACT:  PHONE NUMBER 000-000-0000 X-0000
*** SPECIAL HANDLING CODE: 02 DELIVER WEEKDAY STATUS CODE: 33-VENDOR TRANSPORTATION DELAY MISSING SHIPT/ NOT LOCATED MISSING SHIPTS/ NOT LOCATED
```

Comment: whats the difference, both the output looks same.

Comment: What does "show as" mean? Where is this showing? What programming language or client environment are you using?

Comment: So you just want to force arbitrary linebreaks in a display of some kind?

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand the purpose of this, but I think if you are trying to do it on SSMS, here is a query:

```
declare @strPrint Varchar(2000)
select @strPrint=replace('*** CERPS Generated Case [06/25/2013 01:41:13 AM] C0   *** CREATED:  06/25/2013 AT 09:40 BY 0000000  AT RUHA *** CONTACT:  PHONE NUMBER 000-000-0000 X-0000 *** SPECIAL HANDLING CODE: 02 DELIVER WEEKDAY STATUS CODE: 33-VENDOR TRANSPORTATION DELAY MISSING SHIPT/ NOT LOCATED MISSING SHIPTS/ NOT LOCATED',
'***',char(10)+'***')
Print @strPrint
```